# function parameter difference

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

Here are two same codes but with different function parameters, but they seem to be outputting same things.

```
void get_rate_drop_factor(int *rate_ml, int *drop, int *drop_per_min)
{
    printf("Enter rate in ml/hr=> ");
    scanf("%d", rate_ml);
    printf("Enter tubin's drop factor(drop/ml)=> ");
    scanf("%d",drop);
    *drop_per_min = (*rate_ml / 60) * *drop;
    printf("The drop rate per minute is: %d\n\n", *drop_per_min);

}
```

from what I learned, those variables with '*' in the parameters are output parameters.

```
void get_rate_drop_factor(int *drop_per_min)
    {
        int rate_ml, drop;
        printf("Enter rate in ml/hr=> ");
        scanf("%d", &rate_ml);
        printf("Enter tubin's drop factor(drop/ml)=> ");
        scanf("%d",&drop);
        *drop_per_min = (rate_ml / 60) * drop;
        printf("The drop rate per minute is: %d\n\n", *drop_per_min);

    }
```

when I call the function, those two codes seem to be outputting the same thing. So what exactly is the '*' doing for the parameters?
I don't think I'm completely understanding the concept of parameters.

Please explain nicely because I really want to learn this and It's been really frustrating.

Comment: first function return *rate_ml* and *drop* for caller and second no

Comment: @John Boi Truly speaking nobody knows what '*' is doing in your functions.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from what I learned, those variables with '*' in the parameters are
>   output parameters.

You correctly pointed out that such parameters are output parameters.

So in the first function all three parameters are output parameters.

In the second function there is only one output parameter. So the caller of the function can not get values of `rate_ml` and `drop` entered by the user in the function.

So if the caller of the function needs to get all three values he should use the first function declaration. If he needs only the value of the result calculation he should use the second function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The function parameters are also basically local variables for the function, so you can use them as such as the first example show this. `int *drop` for example can be overwritten in the function as it is happen in your example and that is why there is no declaration like `int rate_ml, drop;`, since it use the 2nd and 3rd parameter as local variables.

But this is not the normal use of them. The normal use case is to be able to give values to a function as arguments to work with. Your first function ignores these incoming values and overwrites them with the result of `scanf` thus using them as local variables basically. That is why the the function essentially behave the same. But this is a not the way it should be used. The second form is the more clear and logical and expected.

Also note if you would do this for the first function header:

```
void get_rate_drop_factor(int *rate_ml, int const *drop, int const *drop_per_min)
```

Then it would not work anymore and also this is usually a good practice to declare function arguments as `const` to not overwrite them accidentally, because most of the time you just want to read them.